# Show different page depending on user role

Tags: plugins, redirect, user-roles

I am quite new at WordPress and sitebuilding in general but I have built a site that I am pleased with.

We are working with companies in four different countries and I want my customers to be able to create their own accounts on the site so they can log in and see files that are not available for non-logged in visitors.

I have used the Ultimate Member plug in for the registration and log in pages, but we have different files we want to be seen depending what country the user is based in.

I have used the "Role ID" to be able to handle this.

After that I have tried to redirect from one page to another depending on what "Role ID" the one who clicks on the button has. But this works quite bad, it redirects to the wrong page more often than not...

Could anyone please help a newbie out here?

Thanks!

Comment: If the users are recording their country when they sign up then you can retrieve that meta data at the same time you check for `is_user_logged_in()` and then depending on what the meta data is, you can display different content.  I don't think redirects are the best way to go about doing this, but it all depends on what access you have to augment and change the way the information is displayed and collected.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.